# How to count the rows in a DataTable based on the row values

Tags: javascript, datatable

I have a datatable in which i am storing some data.Now my need is that i want to count the rows on the basis of the row values.How to achieve that.I am posting my dataTable code

```
$("div.loader").show();
$("#backgroundPopup").show();
$("#backgroundPopup").css("opacity", "0.7");
var url = "<%=byopenjobResourceURL%>";
var type = "onLoadForByOpenJob";
var createTable = '<table id="mainTable" class="display"><thead><tr><th>Create Date</th><th>Job Order</th><th>ID</th><th>Owner</th><th>Client</th><th>Value</th><th>Product</th></thead><tbody>';
var totalActivities = '0';

jQuery.getJSON(url+"&type="+type, function(data) {

    for(var z=0; z<data.searchResultArray.length;z++){
        searchResultArray = data.searchResultArray[z].split("$$##$$##");    
        createTable = createTable + "<tr><td>"+searchResultArray[0]+"</td><td>"+searchResultArray[1]+"</td><td>"+searchResultArray[2]+"</td><td>"+searchResultArray[3]+"</td><td>"+searchResultArray[4]+"</td><td>"+searchResultArray[5]+"</td><td>"+searchResultArray[6]+"</td></tr>";         


    }



$('#mainTable').dataTable({
        "scrollY":        300,
        "scrollCollapse": true,
        "jQueryUI":       true,
        "aaSorting": []
    });
```

[image]

How to achieve that?Lets say i want to count the product column by its content.i.e i want to how many Search - Contigent is there

Comment: HTML for the table would be a great addition to solve this question.

Comment: I am trying this var table = $('#mainTable').DataTable();
 var rows = table.rows('.Staffing');
 alert(rows.length)

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can sum up rows in a table

```
<table id="mainTable" class="display">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Create Date</th>
      <th>Job Order</th>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Owner</th>
      <th>Client</th>
      <th>Value</th>
      <th>Product</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function sumTable() {
    var rows = $('tbody tr'),
      result = [],
      sumLine = $('<tr>');
    rows.each(function(index, item){
      $(item).find('td').each(function(index, cell){
        if(!result[index]) { result[index] = 0; }
        result[index] += cell.innerText *1; 
      });
    });
    $.each(result, function(index, item) {
      var cell= $('<td>'); 
      cell.text(item);
      sumLine.append(cell);     
    });
    $('tbody').append(sumLine);
  }
  sumTable();
</script>
```

first cycle through all lines in the tbody and then for each line cycle through each td and sum the contents into an array. Which is added at the end. You could also just get the sum of the array instead of adding it as a row at the end of the table.